# doseq with KafkaStream evaluates previous item

Tags: java, clojure, lazy-sequences

I want to pop messages from a `KafkaStream` and process them.  As `KafkaStream` implements `java.lang.Iterable` I thought I could just put the stream into a `doseq` and it would consume the messages as they come in.  However what happens is that a message is only passed to the body of the `doseq` when another message is added to the `KafkaStream`, 'pushing' it out.

```
(doseq [msg (map unpack-message ^KafkaStream stream)]
    (handler msg))
```

What I have to do is implement what is done in https://github.com/pingles/clj-kafka/blob/master/src/clj_kafka/consumer/zk.clj `lazy-iterate` and build up a seq using the iterator.  This works but I have no idea why, could someone explain?

One other even more weird thing is that if I put a log line in the unpack-message function I see that it is evaluated when the message comes in.  So the message is unpacked in a lazy function `map` but it is not taken from the `doseq` event though it is kind of sitting in there waiting.  I really don't understand.